# Vuejs - - Assigning prop value in child after ajax request in parent.

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am sure I am missing something simple here.  I have created a reusable child component that includes a input like the following, and I am assigning the `initialValue` in the data object from the `itemValue` prop passed to it from the parent.

```
<template>
    <label>{{itemLabel}}</label>
    <input  v-model="initialValue"  type="text" >
</template>
<script>
export default {

    props: ['itemValue'],

    data(){
         return {
               initialValue: this.itemValue,
         }
    }
</script>
```

If in the parent component I assign the `item-value` property directly with a string it works fine.

The problem is I want to set the `item-value` after making an ajax call in the parent, so I am binding it to a data object property that is set by a method using `beforeMount()`

```
<v-child-component :item-value="theValue"></v-child-component>
```

And...

```
data(){
   return {
      theValue: null,
   }
},
methods: {
   setvalue(){
       //make ajax axios get request here then set this.theValue
   }
}
beforeMount(){
    this.setValue();
}
```

When I do it this way the it seems the child's `item-value` is bound to the `null` value before ajax call completes and sets the actual value. How can I achieve my purpose here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want the component to render until `theValue` is set, use the [`v-if` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html):

```
<v-child-component v-if="theValue !== null" :item-value="theValue"></v-child-component>
```

Comment: Bingo!  I knew it was simple.